# Difference between accessing array with $arr[x] and @arr[x]

Tags: arrays, perl, variables

To access array elements, both @ and $ work. For example:

```
@item_price_list = (5 , 8 , 24);
@item_name_list = ("Apple", "Banana", "Mushroom");
print "The price of one @item_name_list[1] is @item_price_list[1] gold coins.\n";
print "The price of one $item_name_list[1] is $item_price_list[1] gold coins.\n";
```

It seems to me that this kind of syntax is irregular: `$` is used to define scalars, but can also be used to refer to an array. In bash we use `$` before a variable when we want refer to it and `$` is not considered as a part of the variable name, but in per, `$` is considered a part of scalar variable. Is `@` not considered as a part of an array name in perl?

Comment: `@item_name_list[1]` is an array slice of one element, see [perldoc perldata](https://perldoc.perl.org/perldata.html#Slices)

Comment: http://modernperlbooks.com/books/modern_perl/chapter_03.html

Comment: If you turn on warnings, one warns and another doesn't.

Answer (score 3):

The leading symbol ('$' or '@') on the array indicates whether you are getting back a singular value (a scalar) or a plural one (a list). This is true whether the list consist of one element as in

```
@item_price_list[1]
```

or multiple elements as in

```
@item_price_list[0..2]
```

One major difference of a list to an array is, that the list in scalar context returns the last element of the list, while an array will return the number of elements in the list.

So adding

```
print "The price of one @item_name_list[1] is " .  @item_price_list[0..2] . " gold coins.\n";
```

would produce

```
The price of one Banana is 24 gold coins.
```

while

```
print "The price of one @item_name_list[1] is " .  @item_price_list . " gold coins.\n";
```

would produce

```
The price of one Banana is 3 gold coins.
```